# How to show a given function satisfies the Cauchy Riemann equation at a point, but is not differentiable at that point.

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, cauchy-riemann-equations

This is my question:

> Prove that the function $f(z) = u+iv$, where
> $$ f(z) = \begin{cases} \frac{x^3(1+i) - y^3(1-i)}{x^2+y^2}, &\text{ if }z\neq 0,\\ 0 &\text{if }z=0.\end{cases}$$
> satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equation at the origin, but the derivative of $f$ at $z=0$ does not exists.

I solved the second part about the derivative but was not able to prove the first part, that is, $u_x=v_y$ at $z=0$. Please kindly direct me how to solve it: I got

\begin{align*}
u_x&=\frac{x^4 +3x^2x^2 + 2xy^3}{(x^2 + y^2)^2}, \\ 
u_y&=\frac{ -y^4 -2x^3y -3x^2y^2}{(x^2 + y^2)^2}, \\
v_x&= \frac{x^4 - 2xy^3 + 3x^2y^2}{(x^2 + y^2)^2}, \\
v_y&=\frac{y^4+2x^2y^2-2x^3y}{(x^2 + y^2)^2}.
\end{align*}

and there remains the question of how to prove $u_x=v_y$ at $(x,y)=(0,0)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: This reads like a demand. Zero effort + being rude is a recipe for mass downvoting.

Comment: I edited your question, so that it is a bit more readable. You may click "edit" to edit your question, and to see how latex is used in this site.

Comment: Thank you @arctic char

Comment: There's a typo in the numerator of the formula for $u_x$, isn't there?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Unfortunately it seems the OP is not coming back.